# Using Oracle CONTAINS Clause for 2 columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

How can I use CONTAINS clause for searching from 2 columns of a table.
For eg:- lets say I have a table named CONTACT. It contains columns like FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, USERNAME, EMAIL etc.

Now if I want to search for a string, say 'ABCD' in the column USERNAME using CONTAINS clause, I'll write:

```
SELECT * 
FROM CONTACT 
WHERE (CONTAINS(USERNAME, 'ABCD', 1)> 0);
```

It gives me the desired result. But what If I have to search the string on 2 columns? I tried using:-

```
SELECT * 
FROM CONTACT 
WHERE (CONTAINS(USERNAME, 'ABCD', 1)> 0)
AND (CONTAINS(FIRST_NAME, 'ABCD', 1)> 0);
```

But it gives me an error. Please help me with this.

PS: Indexes on columns have been created as required for using CONTAINS clause.

Comment: Can you please post the error message?

Comment: ORA-29907: found duplicate labels in primary invocations
29907. 00000 -  "found duplicate labels in primary invocations"
*Cause:    There are multiple primary invocations of operators with
           the same number as the label.
*Action:   Use distinct labels in primary invocations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your label is not unique, try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM CONTACT 
WHERE (CONTAINS(USERNAME, 'ABCD', 1)> 0)
AND (CONTAINS(FIRST_NAME, 'ABCD', 2)> 0);
```

Comment: JWK: thanx for that. It does work now. But can you elaborate on what's the logic behind this?

Comment: Oracle needs to keep track of the scores and needs a unique label for this to do so. This way it enables you to use the score else where in the SQL Statement, e.g the select part.

Comment: But will it make any difference if I interchange the scores. Or say I search only on USERNAME and use 2 as its score?

Comment: If you have only one `CONTAINS` on USERNAME it should not matter what number you put in there. Same thing for switching the 1 and 2, that should not make a difference.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, if you are using contains clause more than once, then you can skip the label:

`SELECT * 
FROM CONTACT 
WHERE (CONTAINS(USERNAME, 'ABCD')> 0)
AND (CONTAINS(FIRST_NAME, 'ABCD')> 0);`

It automatically adds the labels.